# Create a POJO using JSON data

Tags: java, json, rest, jaxb

I am having a JSON coming from response payload of rest API. below is structure of simplified JSON but the actual is much more complex.

```
{
    "hardware": {
        "cores": 2,
        "cpu": 1,
    },
    "name": "machine11",
    "network": [
        {
            "interface_name": "intf1",
            "interface_ip": "1.1.1.1",
            "interface_mac": "aa : aa: aa: aa: aa"
        }
     ]
}
```

Now I have to write POJO class to bind the JSON structure using JAXB annotations (javax.xml.bind.annotation.*).
Can anyone help me how to write POJO class for a complex JSON structure,converting JSON to XML and then using XML schema to generate class is not helping out is there any other way?
Thanks in advance:-)

Comment: Check [jsonschema2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org). This site helps to convert JSON to POJO class.

Comment: Also there is JSON32POJO maven plugin. Refer link: [link](https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo)

Answer (score 2):

As per the above JSON structure, your Java objects will look like this:

```
public class OutermostClass{

    private Hardware hardware;
    private String name;
    private Set<Network> network = new HashSet<Network>;

}

public class Hardware {

    private int cores;
    private int cpu;
}

public class Network {
    private String interface_name;
    private String interface_ip;
    private String interface_mac
}
```

Comment: Multiple public is not allowed in file